# Find Text Between 2 Quotes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

ok, so I have this small block of text:

```
function onfocus(event) {
  if ($(this).val() == "Some Arbitrary Text") {$(this).val("");}
}
```

Using jQuery or JavaScript, I would like to find teh "Arbitrary Text".  This text block is constant, with the exception of the "Arbitrary Text".  Ideally, I would like a way to parse it without using complicated loops and regex.

To help clarify:
The fact that the text is javascript plays no part.  Think of it as just text I am parsing.  The "Arbitrary Text" can be anything, I am trying to find the text between the 2 quotes.

Comment: the text to search into (aka "the haystack") is actually the whole chunk of code or the "Some Arbitrary Text" part?

Comment: I am trying to find the "arbitrary text" in the whole chunk of code

Comment: @downvoter, why don't you give an explanation as to why you downvoted so that I can address the issue.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You don't have write access to the chunk of code itself?  you could store that arbitrary text inside a variable and manipulate it to your heart's content. I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: this code block comes from the "onfocus" event of a control.  I need to find the arbitrary text in order see what the default value was, this will allow me to make sure a default value was not entered.  This is the easiest way, seeing as the inputs are completely dynamic.

Comment: if your inputs are dynamic, you mean they are added via ajax or injection. In such case, right after the injection, initiate a variable containing their default value, then check the control's value against that variable onBlur. Easier like that...

Comment: Listen to @pixeline. This is a very unusual solution to a completely ordinary problem. The right way is either to specify and set the default value in JS, saving it as a global variable, or to use JS to *retrieve* the initial value from the element on page load, and save it as a variable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not that I understood the question completely, but maybe

```
var s = 'foo "quoted" bar';
var m = s.match(/"(.*?)"/);
alert(m[1]); // m[1] = quoted
```

Of course, this is also possible without regexps, but it would make no sense - this is what regexps are for

Comment: it seems regex is the only way to go.  i thought it would be more complicated than this.  How can I get this to return the text without the quotes?

Comment: @Russ: as per my answer, to get rid of quotes: string = string.replace(/"/g, '');

Comment: You missed a semicolon on line 2.

Comment: A couple semicolons (fixed). Just a tiny note, AFAIK some browsers will allow you to DO Javascript without semicolons, but it's still a very good idea to include them.

Comment: @user187291 what if I need to match multiple quoted substrings? i.e. `"the cat" "super"`

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $(this).val().replace(/"(.*?)"/ig, "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing - are you looking to see if a large string contains a smaller string?  If so, use the [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) function like this:

```
function onfocus(event) {
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("Some Arbitrary Text") > 0) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
}
```

Comment: no, the arbitrary text changes.  I need to find it to evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringToSearchFor = 'if ($(this).val() == "';
var haystack = 'put your javascript code here';

var startPosition = haystack.indexOf(stringToSearchFor);
```

Comment: This is close, but I need to pull that text out of the code block and be able to put it into a variable, but this gets me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you just need a regular expression:

```
astring = "oh hai I'm a string my name is \"Arbitrary Text\"";
results = astring.match(/"[\d\w\s]*"/g);
```

The regexp `/"[\d\w\s]*"/` will match any digit, word or whitespace characters appearing between inverted commas. The suffix `g` indicates the search is global, and returns an array of all matches. Removing the g will simply return the first result.

In this case `match()` returns a 1-member array: `['"Arbitrary Text"']`. Yes, it includes the inverted commas. To remove them: `string = string.replace(/"/g, '');`

Null is returned if no match is found in the text.

[Good javascript-regexp cheatsheet here.](http://www.evolt.org/article/Regular_Expressions_in_JavaScript/17/36435/)

**Edit**

Now that we understand your rationale for doing this, I have to recommend against this method.

There are any number of ways to compare a form input's text to its default value. You could store the default value in a global JS variable, for instance, or as an attribute of the html element itself.

That is not to say your method is "wrong", but this code has a serious [aroma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are actually displaying some kind of "invite" message inside an input element like, for example: "put your name here" inside a text input. Of course, you want this invite to disappear as soon as the user focuses on that input, and have it reappear if the user didn't put anything in the input. The intention is right, but your approach is a bit dirty and unreliable. I would use variables instead.

Since your inputs are added dynamically, simply add the variable inside a < script> tag right after the html injection. for example:

```
document.write('<input id="controller24" type="text" name="email" value="Put your name here"/><script>var controller24Default="Put your name here";</script>');
```

After that, you should bind that controller a generic function that reconstruct the default variable out of the input id value. `var thisDefaultValue = eval("controller"+this.id+"Default")`. Just an idea.