# Find special markers in sequence and do something to the text in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I wanna do something that would work much like this shortcode in stackexchange.

So basically I want to wrap text with distinct markers and `.wrap()` them in spans with specific classes accordingly... while also removing the markers that once existed.

I found this [Find Text Between 2 Quotes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684116/find-text-between-2-quotes-with-jquery)  but it gives little help as i could only make it work as it was.

This explains a little further: http://jsfiddle.net/ALfsT/3/

I have no idea where to go with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Guffa for the help here

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/AkCED/

```
var res = {
    boldIt:/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g,
    underlineIt:/\_\_(.*?)\_\_/g
}
var txt = $( "#texts" ).html();
$.each(res, function(type, re) {
  txt = txt.replace( re, '<span class="'+type+'" >$1</span>' );
});
$( "#texts" ).html(txt);
```

---

update:

now we need to code stuff like this http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/bhTAM/

You changed to class=texts I changed it back to id=texts and it worked better

```
var res = {
    boldIt:{re:/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g,tag:"span"},
    underlineIt:{re:/\_\_(.*?)\_\_/g,tag:"span"},
    italicIt:{re:/\/\/(.*?)\/\//g,tag:"span"},
    titleIt:{re:/\=\=(.*?)\=\=/g,tag:"h1"},
    linkIt:{re:/\#\#(.*?)\:(.*?)\#\#/g, tag:"a"},
    imageIt:{re:/\"\"(.*?)\:(.*?)\"\"/g, tag:"img"}
}
var s = $("#texts").html();    
$.each(res, function(type, obj) {
  if(s) s = s.replace(obj.re,'<'+obj.tag+' class="'+type+'" >$1</'+obj.tag+'>');
});
$("#texts").html(s);
```

Comment: :/ weird that it runs only once. Nothing ive tried have worked to fix that yet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/GyPHH/20/ - the reaqson it only runs once is that when you execute the regex it just gives you the first match. Then you execute it again for the next and so on. I've modified what you've done and got it working nicely. And I do like the way your underlining class italicises things. ;-) And as a last note the javascript left is a bit rubbish since I just fixed it with minimal changes (so the last each is actually probably best removed, etc.)

Comment: Well, everything seems to be going quite fine.. Except that i have no idea why underline doesnt work with others Unless you insert it first. (See the comments in the code.. im working on it but just quite cant understand why.. Yet.) Also the way it adds every single `shortcode` as their own spans.. I cant figure out how i could change it to add span around the text and then add each of the classes in that one span instead.. Gotta say Big hand to both of you @mplungjan and @Chris ( By the way.. I added a divider that can be used to divide it into columns. http://jsfiddle.net/GyPHH/21/ )

Comment: By the way.. You guys wouldnt happen to have ideas how i could make shortcodes for links and images as well. Deeper explanation in the html comments at bottom and in js comments i have some weak attempt to find those thingies. http://jsfiddle.net/GyPHH/22/

Comment: I might have exploded the code into pieces but it seems to work.. ( my javascript knowledge is nonexistent ) http://jsfiddle.net/bhTAM/4/ Only thing that still bothers me is is the way those styles are added by making new element for on top of the last one. Got any ideas for that? Basically `**==Bold & Title==**` generates to `<span class="boldIt titleIt">Bold & Title</span>`. I do understand why it generates it like it does right now, but i have absolutely no idea on how i could.. like create the span first and add the classes afterwards..

Comment: I am sorry, I am NOT writing you an editor/text parser. That would be like real work and there are a gazillion html editors out there, including the one we are using now called markdown. Also please read this, which was posted in a question I asked to help me help you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine

Comment: If its that difficult, i can understand that. ..I still tried to make some crappy solution but i was never able to get it to generate just one span, lol. Well, it's good enough for me as it is. This was not meant for text area actually. It started from that divider cause i wanted to make it easier to make columns that also work in lower versions of ie ..so this is manual but quite fast and easy.. as you just have to write `----` whenever you want to divide part of text. but, then I just got carried away with the idea of making other shortcodes.. :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `*` characters : `/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/`

I also suggest that you use a callback function to wrap your text :
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example.3a_Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters)