# Finding the text between first and last quote of a line

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to build a simple page that will remove text before the first quotation marks in a line and the text after the last quote (including the final quote) in a line within a textarea.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684116/find-text-between-2-quotes-with-jquery) question was immensely helpful and got me to the following code:

```
    $('#desqlize').on('click', function(){
        var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
        var total = ""
        $.each(lines, function(){
            var enteredText = String(this); 
            var m = enteredText.match(/"(.*?)"/);
          total = total + m[1] +'\n'
        })
        $('textarea').val(total);   
    });
```

However, if the text in the textarea had quotation marks within the line, such as the text listed below, it would remove the text within those quotations as well.

```
cmd2.CommandText = cmd2.CommandText & "AND b.ColumnID IN     ("&"'"&REPLACE(level2Array(1,0), ",", "','" )&"'"&") "
```

Someone would be pasting a block of lines like the above and I, essentially, want to remove everything from cmd2 until the first quotation mark and then remove the final quotation mark for each line.  Everything within these two quotation marks I would like to remain.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, but how about just splitting on quotes, and pop()'ing off the end and shift()'ing off the start ?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you are saying, I think that's what my current method does.  If I split on any quote, it's going to pop off text from the middle of the line, when I only want to remove the front and end.

Comment: You want to remove all text up to and including the first `"`? And the ending `"`?

Comment: @hwnd Yes.  Exactly that.  The ending `"` and everything after it on that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for all cases where there are quotation marks in the input:

```
var parsed = $('textarea').val().replace(/^[^"]*"(.*)"[^"]*$/, '$1');
```

Or without regex:

```
var ta = $('textarea').val();
var parsed = ta.substring(ta.indexOf('"') + 1, ta.lastIndexOf('"'));
```

To put this in context with your code above:

```
$('#desqlize').on('click', function(){
    var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
    var total = ""
    $.each(lines, function(){
        var enteredText = String(this); 
        total = total + enteredText.replace(/^[^"]*"(.*)"[^"]*$/, '$1') + '\n';
        // or, alternatively:
        // total = total + enteredText.substring(enteredText.indexOf('"') + 1, enteredText.lastIndexOf('"'));
    })
    $('textarea').val(total);
});
```