# I have a CasperJS script that outputs a string, how can I trim the text

Tags: javascript, trim, casperjs

Here is my script from CasperJS:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'https://example.wsw/';
casper.start('https://example.wsw/login.html', function() {
    //this.echo(this.getTitle());
    //this.download(url, 'google_company.html');
    this.echo(this.getHTML('img#cpt_img', true));
});

casper.run();
```

The out put I get from this is:

```
<img id="cpt_img" src="/user/turing/image.asp?1394574424">
```

and this is what I am trying to get it the output:

```
/user/turing/image.asp?1394574424
```

so I can use this string above later when I need it.

Can anyone show me away to change the string to what I need in the output?

Comment: use evaluate and css selector. read http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html under "Now let’s scrape Google!"

Comment: hanks for he commen will have a look now i am reading he documenaion but got stuck haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var imgTag = this.getHTML('img#cpt_img', true);
var src = imgTag.match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1];
```

Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1684206/3351720

Comment: this.echo(this.getHTML('img#cpt_img', true).match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1]);

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
this.echo(this.getElementAttribute('img#cpt_img', 'src'));
```