# JS grabbing any text in the dom that has double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking for a script that will check the page for any text that has double quotes e.g. Hello world, "this is a great example". So grabbing "this is a great example" and wrapping it in an `<em>` tag

So the result will be `<em>"this is a great example"</em>`

Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried anything? where are you stuck?

Comment: Does this have to be native JS or can jQuery get involved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684116/find-text-between-2-quotes-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy to achieve with jQuery:

```js
$('body :not(script, style)').contents().filter(function() {
  // find text nodes in <body> ignoring <script> and <style> tags
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
  // find quoted text and wrap it with <em> tags
  return this.nodeValue.replace(/"[^"]+"/g, '<em>$&</em>');
});
```

```css
span {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  Hello world! "This is a great example"<br>
  <span>Hello world! "This is a great example"</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the regex in the whole page using javascript like this:

`var matchingText = document.documentElement.innerHTML.match(/"(.*?)"/);`

The result will be an array with Strings in double quotes.

Than you can iterate through them and add `<em>` tag to each one of them.